# Why does the clipped objects position reset when applying eyedropper color to a mask in InDesign CC?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, mask, configuration, eyedropper

I'm working on an icon project where I have images clipped into circles of varying colors, bleeding off the bottom. I'm also creating a color scheme, in smaller circles, which is then applied to the icons.

Here's how the clipped image is supposed to be oriented in the mask:
[image: clipped image bleeding off bottom]

Unfortunately, when I use the eyedropper to apply color from my scheme to the icon, it seems to reset the clipped image so that it centers in the circle.

It copies the color, but changes the placement of the image:
[image: circle has new color, but image has shifted]

I've tried double-clicking the eyedropper and unchecking everything but fill color, but no luck. I've got some workarounds going right now, so I don't need suggestions for that, but does anyone know why this is happening? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Welcome Heather! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Comment: Hi Vincent! Thanks for the welcome. Of course I only asked the question after unsuccessful searches elsewhere. I've just joined the site, so I guess I'm not totally sure how things work yet. Are these more technical questions frowned upon here? Just wondering, since I see so many of them, and Rsiel gave me a very helpful answer below.

Comment: We tend to shy away from questions that are essentially product support, for they are a way better fit for the actual software's website. That said, we do have a lot of knowledge of the software and like to help. If you want to know mare, please give the [help] a read or ping one of us in [chat] once your rep reaches 20. Please keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess, but I believe it has something to do with this option:

In the Menu: Object > Fitting > Frame Fitting Options

[image: frame fitting options]

There is a setting here to **Align From**.

The small circles that you created may have this attribute set when they were created, and the Eye Dropper is grabbing it even though you don't want it to.

I suggest selecting all the small circles, Right-clicking on them. Then select **Fitting > Clear Frame Fitting Options**.